# react-select creatable defaultInputValue not working

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have created a `CreatableSelect` control and set the `defaultInputValue` property. Although the default value gets displayed on the control when control is loaded, after the first time I click on the control (either on the the textbox or the drop down symbol) the list does not display and on click again the default value is replaced by 'Select...' and then the list is displayed.

I would expect the default value not to be cleared when I click on the control unless I explicitly clear it. I would want the default value to remain until I make a selection in the dropdown or clear the value myself

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


import CreatableSelect from 'react-select/creatable';

export default class CreatableSingle extends Component<*, State> {
  handleChange = (newValue: any, actionMeta: any) => {
    console.group('Value Changed');
    console.log(newValue);
    console.log(`action: ${actionMeta.action}`);
    console.groupEnd();
  };
  handleInputChange = (inputValue: any, actionMeta: any) => {
    console.group('Input Changed');
    console.log(inputValue);
    console.log(`action: ${actionMeta.action}`);
    console.groupEnd();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <CreatableSelect
        isClearable
        defaultInputValue ={'Yellow'}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
        options={ [
          { value: 'ocean', label: 'Ocean' },
          { value: 'blue', label: 'Blue' },
          { value: 'purple', label: 'Purple' },
          { value: 'red', label: 'Red' }]}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

The above code is from the https://react-select.com/home .. Have added  below line since i would have a default value ( coming from database )  also the default value 'Yellow' is not part of the options array
`defaultInputValue ={'Yellow'}`

Comment: any suggestions/help please?

Comment: Did you try `defaultValue` instead of `defaultInputValue` as suggested on the answer?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `defaultInputValue` is used to set the initial value of the search input based on their [readme](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select#controllable-props).

I think for what you are trying to do you need `defaultValue` prop:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CreatableSelect from 'react-select/creatable';

export default class CreatableSingle extends Component<*, State> {
  handleChange = (newValue: any, actionMeta: any) => {
    console.group('Value Changed');
    console.log(newValue);
    console.log(`action: ${actionMeta.action}`);
    console.groupEnd();
  };

  handleInputChange = (inputValue: any, actionMeta: any) => {
    console.group('Input Changed');
    console.log(inputValue);
    console.log(`action: ${actionMeta.action}`);
    console.groupEnd();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <CreatableSelect
        isClearable
        defaultValue={{ value: 'red', label: 'Red' }}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
        options={ [
          { value: 'ocean', label: 'Ocean' },
          { value: 'blue', label: 'Blue' },
          { value: 'purple', label: 'Purple' },
          { value: 'red', label: 'Red' }]}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am happy I could help! Consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. In that way, you help others with similar issues to find their way

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:) types of searchTags and savedTags are not the same. You have to create them separately.

[image]

[image]

[image]